# Preserved quantity in a flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am currently learning about Fluid Dynamics, and I do not understand how if $\frac{Df}{Dt}=0$ then the quantity $f(\mathbf x(t),t)$ is "preserved following the flow".

I asume that "preserved following the flow" would mean that, fixing a value for $\mathbf x$, we have that $f$ is constant, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$?

But $\frac{Df}{Dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla f$, where $\mathbf u$ is the velocity field, so somehow we need to show that $\mathbf u \cdot \nabla f=0$?

Any enlightenment would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can think of yourself as an observer moving with the flow. For more details, please look up Liouville's Theorem in classical mechanics.

Comment: Imagine the temperature at time $t=0$ is given by $T=T_0+\alpha x$, and the velocity has the constant, uniform, value $U$ and is in the x-direction.  Then, if you measure the temperature at $x=0$, you will get $T=T_0-U \alpha t$.  But no actual cooling is happening: you are just seeing the arrival of cooler water.  If you move along with the flow, you see no change.  If you care about the actual heating/cooling, you want the material derivative, not the partial derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"preserved following the flow" means preserved as you follow a fluid particle during its motion. Suppose that a fluid particle is located at position $(x,y,z)$ at time $t$ and has velocity $(u,v,w)$. An infinitesimal time $dt$ later (i.e. at time $t+dt$) the fluid particle's position changes to $(x+u~dt,y+v~dt,z+w~dt)$. Suppose $T(t,x,y,z)$ is the temperature field of the fluid as measured by a stationary observer. According to this observer the moving fluid particle's temperature at time $t$ is $T(t,x,y,z)$ and at time $t+dt$ is $T(t+dt,x+u~dt,y+v~dt,z+w~dt)$. If the fluid particle's temperature is to remain constant then we must have:
\begin{align}
T(t+dt,x+u~dt,y+v~dt,z+w~dt)-T(t,x,y,z)&=0\\
\left[ T(t,x,y,z)+\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}u~dt+\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}v~dt+\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}w~dt \right]-T(t,x,y,z)&=0\\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}+v\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}+w\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}&=0
\end{align}
The same argument goes through for any other physical quantity instead of temperature.